# Override Selected Item in Combobox's style to show comboxbox's background not gray background

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I am having an issue with getting a custom property set with a combobox.  I am using .Net 4.0, WPF with xaml resources for types set in a dictionary and some brushes set in the app.xaml.  I can get the nice rounded corner just find and a gradient and layout to my combobox using the surrounding 'border' trick.  However I can't seem to get the 'Selected Item' in the combobox to have a background other than dull gray.  I would prefer to change it to transparent and inherit the gradient of the parent border.  However I am missing the property or relationship to do this.

Does anyone know how to do this in the xaml?

Image:

[image: Combobox Current showings of Selections and selected]

code:

Dictionary item:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MoneyBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#071C07" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  </Style>
```

Brush in main App.xaml:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MoneyBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#3A883A" Offset="1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF53AA75" Offset="0.50" />
            <GradientStop Color="#073307" Offset="0.95" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FontBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#107810" Offset="0.50" />
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.65" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Actual item in mainwindow:

```
<Border Margin="5" >
                    <ComboBox Height="30" Width="170" Margin="10" x:Name="combopersons" 
                    FontSize="20"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
                    SelectedValuePath="PersonId"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentUser}"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource FontBrush}">
                    </ComboBox>
                </Border>
```

---

EDIT >>>

I like the solution proposed by @iltzortz, but I wanted a gradient so in this case this would work better:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" >
        <GradientStop Color="#3A883A" Offset="1" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF53AA75" Offset="0.50" />
        <GradientStop Color="#073307" Offset="0.95" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" >
        <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="1" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

EDIT 2 >>>

For some reason this will only work on applications I have built using .NET 4.0 or higher on Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 7.  When I try to run the code at home for some reason
it won't render I believe this is due to either Windows 8 or Visual Studio 2010 interpreting different colors for different system values.  Be aware of this if you have Windows 8 or Visual Studio 2010 as it will work for me for one environment but not the other...  curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to do the job

```
<Grid Background="Pink">

    <ComboBox Margin="10,0" Width="100" Height="40">
        <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>            
        <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
        </ComboBox.Resources>            
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: also try SystemColors.ControlBrushKey

Comment: That only makes the first part of the picture have all four boxes uniform colors from the selection.  It still does not set the 'set' item once selected as the color specified.  I need to figure out that property.  I am trying to override a lot of SystemColors and not finding it.

Comment: I edited my answer could you check if this gets the result you want? If i understood well this seems to get the result you want

Comment: You are on the right track but you are setting a solid and not a gradient.  I got the properties I need though so I will give you the answer.  My final property I edited your answer, hope you don't mind.